# Laravel 5.4 using Geoip

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to use the **antonioribeiro/tracker** package for Laravel, but in order to get geoip you have to either to install geoip v 1.14 or 2.

After installation I can't add a facade and alias in the configuration file. How can I fix this?.

**My composer.json file**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "geoip/geoip": "~1.14",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "pragmarx/tracker": "^3.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
```

How do I add an alias and facade in the configuration file?

Comment: You can't? As in you can't type it in your config/app.php?

Comment: I can but  i dont know it its not written in documentation.@Robert

Comment: You mean this: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#installing ?

Comment: yes @Robert. but you need that geoip to capture location, tracker is working okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geoip package is not a Laravel package. In order to have a facade or something similar, you'll need a Laravel wrapper or create it yourself.

Existing Laravel package: [torann/laravel-geoip](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip)

Some basic usage information: [laravel-geoip basic usage](http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/basic-usage.html)

Basically, after installing you can use the helper method `geoip()`, or you can choose to set a Facade, but it's not required.

Most of these packages use `geoip2`, so you can remove `"geoip/geoip": "~1.14",` from your `composer.json` file. Including the package will also install `geoip2`